# grails grom create criteria with many-to-many mapping

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have two domain classes: User and Book.

```
class Book implements Serializable{


    String bookName
    Timestamp createdDateTime

    Blob file


    static belongsTo = [User]
    static hasMany  = [user :User]
}
```

I am able to add user in book using `addToUser()` method.

But I am stuck in create criteria while applying filter in user.

```
def query = Book.createCriteria();

def results = query.list () {
    eq("user",userObject) // not working since user field is a list of users.
    order("createdDateTime", "desc")
}
```

Please help me with the correct way of filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the user table first in a many-to-many relation. The criteria should look like:

```
Book.withCriteria {
    user {
        eq("id", userObject.id)
    }
    order("createdDateTime", "desc")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure how you're trying to model your domain but maybe you want a Book to have a single user? In which case you'd have the belongsTo relationship on Book e.g.

```
class Book {
    String bookName
    Timestamp createdDateTime
    Blob file
    static belongsTo = [user: User]
}
```

Then have the hasMany relationship on User e.g.

```
class User {
    String name
    static hasMany = [books: Book]
}
```

Then you can look Books up with criteria like:

```
def user = User.findByName( 'bob' )

def results = Book.createCriteria().list () {
    eq( "user", user )
    order( "createdDateTime", "desc" )
}
```

Comment: Its not working, since user field is a list of user objects.

Comment: In my answer it's not a list because it's been remodelled so a Book has a single User but a User can have many Books