# How to query all the owned objects in one query MTM?

Tags: postgresql, grails, grails-orm

I have a list of the owning side of a many-to-many relationship. How do I query all the owned objects in one query using Grails GORM? In SQL I would used the join table and the owned table and the ids for the owning table with an in clause.

Example domain classes:

```
class Book {
  static belongsTo = Author
  static hasMany = [authors:Author]
  String title
}

class Author {
  static hasMany = [books:Book]
  String name
}
```

So I have a List or Set of Authors and I want to find all their Books in one query.

```
select b.*
  from book b
  join author_book ab on b.id = ab.book_id
 where ab.author_id in (1, 2, 3);
```

In Grails I tried the following but it fails.

```
def books = Book.withCriteria {
  inList('authors', authors)
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [node-postgres: how to execute "WHERE col IN (<dynamic value list>)" query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720420/node-postgres-how-to-execute-where-col-in-dynamic-value-list-query)

Comment: It's rather a duplicate of: [grails grom create criteria with many-to-many mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43959938/grails-grom-create-criteria-with-many-to-many-mapping)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join the author first:

```
def books = Book.withCriteria {
    authors {
        inList('id', authors*.id)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
Book.findAllByAuthorInList(authors)
```